# DCGAN can not get it to run properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have been trying to make a DCGAN to generate 512x512 images. I planned to have a structure like dataset/input/input1.png and dataset/output/output1.png. This for the purpose of giving it real input and expected output. However i can not make it work properly , would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Also i do not understand why even when i did make it work the generated images were relatively small like perhaps 16x16 or 32x32.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
from PIL import Image
import os
from torchvision.utils import save_image
import torchvision.models as models
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau

# Define the dataset
class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, input_dir, output_dir, transform=None):
        self.input_dir = input_dir
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.input_filenames = os.listdir(input_dir)
        self.output_filenames = os.listdir(output_dir)

    def __len__(self):
        return min(len(self.input_filenames), len(self.output_filenames))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        input_img_name = self.input_filenames[index]
        output_img_name = self.output_filenames[index]
        input_img_path = os.path.join(self.input_dir, input_img_name)
        output_img_path = os.path.join(self.output_dir, output_img_name)

        input_image = Image.open(input_img_path).convert('RGB')
        output_image = Image.open(output_img_path).convert('RGB')

        if self.transform:
            input_image = self.transform(input_image)
            output_image = self.transform(output_image)
        return input_image, output_image


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels, output_channels, latent_dim):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(latent_dim, 1024, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, output_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(input_channels, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        )
        self.fc = nn.Linear(512 * 4 * 4, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten the tensor
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        return x




# Set device (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Set hyperparameters
input_channels = 3  # Number of input image channels (RGB)
output_channels = 3  # Number of output image channels (RGB)
latent_dim = 100  # Size of the latent vector
lr = 0.0002  # Learning rate
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 1000

# Define transformations for the input images
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),  # Adjust the size as per your requirements
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])

# Create the dataset and data loader
dataset = ImageDataset("dataset/train/input", "dataset/train/output", transform=transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Create the generator and discriminator networks
generator = Generator(input_channels, output_channels, latent_dim).to(device)
discriminator = Discriminator(input_channels).to(device)

# Define the loss functions
adversarial_loss = nn.BCELoss()

# Create optimizer for the generator and discriminator
generator_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
discriminator_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))

# Create learning rate scheduler for the generator and discriminator
generator_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(generator_optimizer, mode='min', patience=10, factor=0.2, verbose=True)
discriminator_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(discriminator_optimizer, mode='min', patience=10, factor=0.2, verbose=True)

# Load generator and discriminator models if available
if os.path.exists("generator.pth"):
    generator.load_state_dict(torch.load("generator.pth"))
    generator.to(device)
    print("Generator model loaded.")

if os.path.exists("discriminator.pth"):
    discriminator.load_state_dict(torch.load("discriminator.pth"))
    discriminator.to(device)
    print("Discriminator model loaded.")

# Training loop
print("Starting training loop...")
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    generator_losses = []
    discriminator_losses = []
    for batch_idx, (input_images, real_images) in enumerate(dataloader):
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Batch [{batch_idx + 1}/{len(dataloader)}]")
        input_images = input_images.to(device)
        real_images = real_images.to(device)

        # Train the discriminator
        discriminator.zero_grad()

        # Real images
        real_labels = torch.ones((real_images.size(0), 1, 5, 5), device=device)
        real_outputs = discriminator(real_images)
        real_loss = adversarial_loss(real_outputs, real_labels)

        # Generate fake images
        latent_vector = torch.randn(input_images.size(0), latent_dim, 1, 1, device=device)
        fake_images = generator(latent_vector)

        # Fake images
        fake_labels = torch.zeros_like(real_labels)
        fake_outputs = discriminator(fake_images.detach())
        fake_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_outputs, fake_labels)

        # Total discriminator loss
        discriminator_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
        discriminator_loss.backward()
        discriminator_optimizer.step()
        discriminator_losses.append(discriminator_loss.item())

        # Train the generator
        generator.zero_grad()

        # Generate fake images again
        fake_outputs = discriminator(fake_images)
        generator_loss = adversarial_loss(fake_outputs, real_labels)

        # Update generator weights
        generator_loss.backward()
        generator_optimizer.step()
        generator_losses.append(generator_loss.item())

        if (batch_idx + 1) % 10 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Batch [{batch_idx + 1}/{len(dataloader)}], "
                  f"Discriminator Loss: {discriminator_loss.item():.4f}, "
                  f"Generator Loss: {generator_loss.item():.4f}")

    generator_scheduler.step(sum(generator_losses) / len(generator_losses))
    discriminator_scheduler.step(sum(discriminator_losses) / len(discriminator_losses))

    # Save generated images
    if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
        generator.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            latent_vector = torch.randn(16, latent_dim, 1, 1, device=device)
            generated_images = generator(latent_vector)
            generated_images = (generated_images + 1) / 2  # Denormalize

            # Save the generated images
            for i, image in enumerate(generated_images):
                filename = f"generated/generated_{epoch + 1}_{i + 1}.png"  # Provide the full path
                save_image(image, filename)

        generator.train()

    print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}] completed.")

# Save the final trained models
torch.save(generator.state_dict(), "generator.pth")
torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), "discriminator.pth")
print("Training completed and models saved.")
```

My current Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kevik\Desktop\my_own_ai\nude_AI\test.py", line 154, in <module>
    real_outputs = discriminator(real_images)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kevik\Desktop\my_own_ai\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kevik\Desktop\my_own_ai\nude_AI\test.py", line 84, in forward
    x = self.fc(x)
        ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kevik\Desktop\my_own_ai\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kevik\Desktop\my_own_ai\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 114, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2x524288 and 8192x1)
```

Comment: You're going to want to read the **minimal** part of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Pretty sure that most introductory texts on linear algebra would explain the part about compatible dimensions for a matrix multiply, so it seems you have some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) work ahead of you to understand where those dimensions went astray. Show an example of simple code that works, plus a slightly bigger example that produces the symptom.